# Unexpected character sequence for <!-- in Asp.net/VB

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I've inherited a VB website (I'm a C# developer by trade) and need to do some changes. On loading it into VS2010 it won't compile/run because it has a `<!-- -->` pair surrounding some code in the style section of each form and VS is saying this is an unexpected character sequence.

I'm assuming it's a vb comment tag, but I've Googled it to no effect and would very much appreciate some help with either making VS accept them, or advice on what to change them to so the original intent is not lost. NB - they appear around 100 times in the code so the former solution would be preferred!

I've tried `<%--` which I use in C# but that doesn't appear to work either.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        <%=Session("PAGE_TITLE")%></title>
    <link href="../../css/sc_english.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:Literal ID="stylesheet1" runat="server" />
    <style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at an ASP.NET website and not a classic ASP website w/ HTML comments?  This is very strange -- you may want to post a snippet of the code you're seeing inside of these comment blocks.

Comment: Yes, `<%-- .. --%>` is the ASP.NET way and has nothing to do with the code-behind language, so it should work in all ASP.NET projects. SO if it doesn't, it could well be not an ASP.NET project!

Comment: Hmmm - that may be the problem then. I'll add a snippet when I figure out how to make it display...

Comment: OK - snippet added. FYI the site is running under .Net 2.0 - could that be a factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- --> is an html (and xml,xhtml etc.) comment block.
```

Sometimes the visual studio designer 'sync'ing can get confused if the comment block contains asp code.

```
<%' Commented stuff here %>
```

is a vb.net comment similar to <%-- in c#

---

### After code sample posted...

The html comment has been placed inside the css styles, it should really be either

```
<!--
    <style type="text/css">

body {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
-->
```

*or*

```
 <style type="text/css">
/*
body {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
*/
</style>
```

i.e. use the html comment to comment out the html  tag or use css comment block 
    /* ... */
to comment out unwanted css styles.

A well crafted regex find-replace or simple work by hand on all affected files will be required to get it sorted correctly I guess.

VS is doings it's job correctly - your other option is to turn off this warning but I would suggest having valid pages is a more sensible goal.

Comment: Excellent! Yes, I agree valid pages is the best way to go. Thanks very much Justin.

Comment: @Mick I don't believe the `<!--` .. `-->` were meant to comment out the styles. This might well be 20th-century-type protection against older browsers making the CSS visible on the screen. So you could just have removed them.